# Ranking for World Cup Predictions system

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I'm making a prediction game for the upcoming world cup.

These are my tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `first_name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `last_name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=9 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;

CREATE TABLE `matches` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `datetime` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `venue` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `stage` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `teamA` varchar(3) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `teamB` varchar(3) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `goalsAinit` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `goalsBinit` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `goalsAadded` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `goalsBadded` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `penaltiesA` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `penaltiesB` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=65 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;

CREATE TABLE `predictions` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_user` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_match` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `goalsAinit` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `goalsBinit` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `goalsAadded` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `goalsBadded` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `penaltiesA` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `penaltiesB` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `points` int(11) DEFAULT '60',
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=11 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;
```

I already have a system for getting the points for a user when they log in the system:

```
for (var j in predictions) {
    if (matches[i].id == predictions[j].id) {
        if(predictions[j].score[0] != null && predictions[j].score[1]!= null){
            if((matches[i].score[0] != null && matches[i].score[1]!= null) && (
            (predictions[j].score[0] > predictions[j].score[1] && matches[i].score[0] > matches[i].score[1]) ||
            (predictions[j].score[0] < predictions[j].score[1] && matches[i].score[0] < matches[i].score[1]) ||
            (predictions[j].score[0] == predictions[j].score[1] && matches[i].score[0] == matches[i].score[1])
            )){
                //prediction correct, add points
            }else{
                //prediction incorrect
            }
        }
    }
    break;
}
```

score is an array of goalsAinit and goalsBinit

But how can I make a ranking for ALL the users? It should be updated quite often (although it doesn't have to be real-time) but I feel as if I execute number 2 for each user everytime I want to update the rank, the DB is going to explode...

Any recommendations? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with this QUERY to calculate the rank for the predictions directly in mysql:

```
SELECT rank, id_user, first_name, last_name, iso, correct, points, total_predictions
FROM (
    SELECT @rank:=@rank+1 AS rank, id_user, first_name, last_name, iso, correct, points, total_predictions
    FROM (
        SELECT  p.id_user, u.first_name, u.last_name, iso,
                SUM(IF((p.goalsAinit > p.goalsBinit AND m.goalsAinit > m.goalsBinit)
                    OR (p.goalsAinit < p.goalsBinit AND m.goalsAinit < m.goalsBinit)
                    OR (p.goalsAinit = p.goalsBinit AND m.goalsAinit = m.goalsBinit), 1, 0)) AS correct,
                SUM(IF((p.goalsAinit > p.goalsBinit AND m.goalsAinit > m.goalsBinit)
                    OR (p.goalsAinit < p.goalsBinit AND m.goalsAinit < m.goalsBinit)
                    OR (p.goalsAinit = p.goalsBinit AND m.goalsAinit = m.goalsBinit), p.points, 0)) AS points,
                COUNT(*) AS total_predictions
        FROM    predictions p
        INNER JOIN matches_debug m ON m.id = p.id_match
        LEFT JOIN users u ON p.id_user = u.id
        LEFT JOIN flags f ON u.country = f.country
        GROUP BY p.id_user
        ORDER BY points DESC, correct DESC, total_predictions DESC, id_user
    ) AS rankings, (SELECT @rank:=0) AS r
) AS overall_rankings;
```

Would this be safe to execute with a large user base as well??

Comment: Without knowing what you think is large, and the resources you're throwing at it, asking if code can hold up to a "large" user base is too vague. If large == 1000 hits/day and the server is on a scalable hosting provider, no problem. If large == 1,000,000 hits/sec and the server is your laptop, the site will likely fail before this code ever runs. In general, nested queries risk performance issues, but depending on the details of your context, that might not matter.

Comment: @acrosman Thanks for your comment. Then a better question would be, is there a way to optimize this query?

Comment: Asking good optimization questions is really hard. If you're going to try, instead of using this space to re-ask the question, I suggest trying in a new question. Start by reading other questions on optimizing queries, and try some of the strategies you see there (also see what questions got helpful responses and which didn't). Once you've tried some things and understand how they impact performance, you might find you don't need to ask anymore.